# Update collection in relation manytomany in Doctrine with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities related with ManyToMany : Routage and Contact.

Entity Routage :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Bdd\Contact", inversedBy="routages", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="routages_contacts")
 */
private $contacts;
```

Entity Contact :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Routage\Routage", mappedBy="contacts")
 */
private $routages;
```

But when I add some Contact to one Routage in his Collection, it creates X queries. 
But I want limit the number of queries.

Here my controller part :

```
foreach($Abonnes as $Contact){
    $Routage->addContact($Contact);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($Routage);
}
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you want the minimum number of queries possible. Do you have performance issues ?

Comment: Hi, yes i want the mininum of queries. Actually i have one insert for one entity in the collection. So if i add 2000 entities i will have 2000 queries...

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($Routage);
```

should be out of the foreach loop so your code should look like this :

```
foreach($Abonnes as $Contact){
    $Routage->addContact($Contact);

}
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($Routage);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```